# Laravel store data auto increment

Tags: php, laravel

```
class PostController extends Controller{
   public $grupID = 1;
   public function store(Request $request)
   {
      $post = new Post();
      $post->GroupID = 'POST-' . $this->grupID;
      $post->save();
      return response()->json($post);
      $this->grupID++;
   }
}
```

Database Structur

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('PostTypeID');
        $table->string('GroupID', 100)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I want to make the groupID auto increment, but it always return 'POST-1'.

Comment: Share how your db/table is looks like ?

Comment: sorry, I reply comment to the wrong person... I have tried your code.. but the groupID does not increase..

Comment: Why groupid is increment in post ?only post id should be incremented by default .can you share exact requirement?

Comment: I have a "Language" table.. so, when I store $post data.. I will make more than 1 record.. If I have two language, I will store 2 record data into my database.. So, when I edit $post with id = 1, I want to get $post data with id =1 and id =2.. that's why I used group ID.. and 2 record data should have same group ID.. that's why, I'm using manual increment

Comment: you increment the grpId AFTER returning the respionse so it is NEVER reached. try to incerement BEFORE returning `response->json(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PostController extends Controller{
   public function store(Request $request)
   {
      $last = DB::table('posts')->last();
      $post = new Post();
      if ($last) {
         $part = explode('-', $last->GroupID);
         $post->GroupID = $part[0] . '-' . ($part[1] + 1);
      } else {
         $post->GroupID = 'POST-1';
      }
      $post->save();
      return response()->json($post);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, you need to get the last value in your DB,

```
class PostController extends Controller{
       public function store(Request $request)
       {
          $lastValue = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('GroupID', 'desc')->first();
          $post = new Post();
          $post->GroupID = 'POST-' . $lastValue->GroupID + 1 ;
          $post->save();
          return response()->json($post);
       }
    }
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: What you said is right, but what you code is wrong. `$lastValue` is object not any integer value. Also what happens if there is no value in table ? You got my point ?

Comment: I got this error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int"

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, i forgot to chain it. @jamesriady answer updated :)

Comment: I have got the solution.. and thankyou for your hint.. 
Sorry for replying your comment lately

Answer (score 1):

in your database migration file
$table->increments('grupID');

and it's automatically increment.

Comment: What is he looking for is, a custom increment :) using String "Post-" (and increment value) not a default value :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use a return statement, the execution stops, so your increment never happens. Put the return statement at the end.

Comment: I have put it at the end, but still the increment not working

Comment: Based on your function the variable will be reset to 1 every time it runs. Are you trying to make it count each time it runs? You will need to submit a value to a db table.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PostController extends Controller{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $groupID = Post::pluck('GroupID')->last();

       $post = new Post();
       $post->GroupID = 'POST-' . $groupID + 1;
       $post->save();
       return response()->json($post);
    }
}
```

$groupID = Post::pluck('GroupID')->last(); 
This gives you the last groupID from the column table (ordered asc by ID).

$post->GroupID = 'POST-' . $groupID + 1; 
This increment the value before saving it in the table.